# How to configure Apache to handle multiple domains with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Tags: ajax, apache

I want to configure Apache to allow XMLHttpRequests from multiple, but not all domains.

This works:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

But it's unsafe, I want to allow domains specified by me, so after a bit of googling I got to this:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://domain1.example http://domain2.example"
```

But this only picks up first domain, the second is not allowed. How to properly specify multiple domains?

Answer (score 45):

you can use `SetEnvIf` in your `.htaccess` file or in in vhost file (inside "Directory" group):

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   SetEnvIfNoCase Origin "https?://(www\.)?(mydomain\.example|mydomain2\.example)(:\d+)?$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
</IfModule>
```

With this code you can allow access from

- `mydomain.example` and `mydomain2.example`
- with or without "www." in front
- with or without port number
- HTTP or HTTPS

You can add multiple domains separated with | or you can use regexp to configure different subdomains or patterns.

Comment: Great, except mine only worked if I put `Header set` instead of `Header add`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you need to remove the $1 from the second line. With it present, any requests over https will fail, because the $1 captures the 's' in https and appends it to the end of the allowed url (so you end up with .coms).

Comment: I see these SetEnvIf solutions everywhere but nobody ever explains **how** they work.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Worked great in my /sites-available/mysite.conf :D

Comment: Confirmed this works superbly, note for localhost with port drop the port number off like this: SetEnvIfNoCase Origin "https?://(www\.)?(localhost|

Comment: This is the only thing that worked from the entire internet