# Cross domain upload class

Tags: php, .htaccess, upload, cross-domain

I finished writing a website and am currently deploying it on a hosting service. This website consists out of 2 separate domains hosted on the same server.
(www.domain1.com & www.domain2.com)

**Situation**

When moving these domains to the hosting service, I figured that 1 script is not working as it was on the local server. This script is a custom upload class in php. This script is located on www.domain1.com but needs to upload the file to www.domain2.com.

My local server is a Xampp server with a simple file structure.

C:/xampp/htdocs

- Domain1/uploadscript.php
- Domain2/destinationfolder/

I am currently using the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` function to navigate towards the other domain. This method works fine for the local server but not on the hosted version see below.

---

**Main issue**

Local server
`print_r ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

> = C:/xampp/htdocs

On domain1.com
`print_r ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

> = /home/myname/domains/domain1/public_html/

On domain2.com
`print_r ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

> = /home/myname/domains/domain2/public_html/

The `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not pointing to the *"domains"* folder but already is pointing to the *"public_html"*.

---

**The question(s)**

How do I navigate towards the *"domains"* folder on my server?
Are there other things necessary for cross domain uploading?

Comment: I'm not sure that understand correctly what "**How do I navigate towards the "domains" folder on my server**" means. Can you explain please ?

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo Sure :)! In short how can I code my way from the domain1/public_html/ to domain2/public_html. Currently I am trying this with the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but using this in a script on domain1 takes me to the /home/myname/domains/domain1/public_html/. So for me it is impossible still to navigate from within the script on domain1 to the destination on domain2. I need this because I use the `move_uploaded_file($tempname, $destination)` method to move the uploaded file to the destination. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It seems you are doing something strange. For sending data from domain A to domain B all you need is **simple form** on domain A and **request handler** on domain B. And also you need to configure CORS (as I write in answer below)

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo Didn't know that it was done like this :) I have tried to find a good example of such a **request handler** but I'm not sure if I am searching the correct thing... Could you point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: ok, I'll try. You can put your **uploadscript** to domain B. On domain A you need only form which allow you to upload file (don't forget to define enctype="multipart/form-data" in this form). You also need to set action as "http:// domainB/uploadscript". That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send some cross domain data, you should set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

You can do this in your `.htaccess` like below:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Be sure that you enabled **mod_headers** in your apache server.

For customizing access you can use something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/10605009/5397119.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/22331450/5397119

Comment: Hi again, I tried to reallocate the upload script as you mentioned. So the current situation is form is on **domain1** and the upload script is located on **domain2**. The `enctype` is in place (was already set). The Header is set like the line supplied above. Now when I try the code an internal server error _500_ even before the script runs. I figure that it might be something with this Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*". How do allow the "mod_headers"? Thanks!

Comment: Hi again, I tried to find an error log but didn't find anything useful. I have solved the issue in another way. I want to thank you for your effort!

Comment: @NealVDV hi. very good. btw, you can post your solution as answer and accept it.